# Unable to restore point in magit commit buffer

Tags: magit, point

When I open commit buffer (pressing <kbd>c c</kbd>), the pointer is shown in random locations instead of showing point at beginning of buffer. This is quite annoying as I have to manually move point every time.

I also checked this [FAQ in magit](http://magit.vc/manual/magit/Point-is-wrong-in-the-COMMIT_005fEDITMSG-buffer.html) and added these to init file

```
(setq session-name-disable-regexp "\\(?:\\`'\\.git/[A-Z_]+\\'\\)")

(with-eval-after-load 'pointback
  (lambda ()
     (when (or git-commit-mode git-rebase-mode)
     (pointback-mode -1))))
```

But still point is not getting restored. I even tried  this

```
(defun restore-point ()
   (interactive)
   (when (string-match ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" buffer-file-name)
      (goto-char (point-min))))
(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook 'restore-point)
```

Still its not restoring. Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Magit [config is here](https://github.com/ChillarAnand/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el#L378-L397) and [emacs config](https://github.com/ChillarAnand/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el).

Comment: Seems like you should try with `emacs -Q` and if that works, then bisect your init file.

Comment: Do you think it could be this package: https://github.com/ChillarAnand/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el#L163

Maybe point is being saved from the last time you edited a commit message?

Comment: @elethan that fixed issue. But if i remove that, how can i  save position of pointer  for other files?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it seems like you could use the function `toggle-save-place` in that library and maybe hook it to the `git-commit-setup-hook` or a similar hook, or do something of that nature to automatically toggle the mode off when you are writing commit messages, and toggle it back on when you are finished.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet to turn off `pointback-mode` from the FAQ misses a crucial part. Here's a fixed version:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'pointback
  (add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook
            (lambda ()
              (when (or git-commit-mode git-rebase-mode)
                (pointback-mode -1)))))
```

I'll update the FAQ later (after checking whether `pointback` offers an option which would make that hack unnecessary.